# update a column in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am having a problem with hibernate in updating a table. I have to move tasks from one project to another and I must update the task id inside that project. The line I am using is:

```
    Long taskCounter = destinationProject.getLastTaskID();
    session.createQuery("update Task tp set tp.projectKey.projectID = ? ,tp.projectKey.id = ?, tp.taskListID = ? where tp.taskListID = ? and tp.projectKey.projectID = ?")
            .setParameter(0, projectID).setParameter(1,++taskCounter).setParameter(2, newTaskListId).setParameter(3, taskListID).setParameter(4, sourceProjectID).executeUpdate();
```

I get an duplicate primary key exception, when I have tasks lists with more than one subtasks. I believe the problem is setParamater(1,++taskCounter) because I believe it's not incremented for every row selected.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you map the table?

Comment: i have a task entity created for the tasks table

Comment: Its not hibernate issue you cannt achive this throught Sql query too... for that either you have to write function or procedure then only it will work

Comment: @Cristi: it would be more helpful if you give the mapping of your classes. The behavior of Hibernate depends greatly on how the classes are mapped.

Comment: @RanuJain: it's a hibernate question. Writing raw sql beat the purpose of using an ORM

Comment: should I use Criteria?